# What is the difference between "berichten" and "erzählen" in the sense of tell, narrate?

Tags: difference, verb

I recently found the verb *berichten* which, if I am not wrong, mainly is used to express *to report something to someone*, in a sort of official way.

Then I also found that *berichten* can be used like *erzählen*, telling something to someone.

I was wondering about the difference in connotation and usage of these two verbs.

I guess that *erzählen* is more used, but how would it sound if instead I would use *berichten*?

> Ich habe ihm alles erzählt.
>
> Ich habe ihm alles berichtet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Berichten* is quite formal and typically implies that the story being told is true (to the best of the teller’s knowledge) while *erzählen* is just telling a story. It might be a fictional story, a fairy tale or whatnot, but could also be a report about a fact or true event.

Think of the words *Geschäftsbericht* (business report), or *Unfallbericht* (accident report). Those are cases where *berichten* would be the word of choice. On the other hand, when you tell someone about your holidays, you would use *erzählen*.

To sum it up *berichten* is closer to *relate* or *report*, depending on the situation. *Erzählen* is closer to *narrate*.

Answer (score 1):

The word *berichten* is *only* used in an official-ish context. Examples:

> Berichten Sie mir bitte bis morgen, was Sie letzte Woche erreicht haben! (context: boss’ speech at work.)
>
> Der Sachverständige berichtete … (translation: reported)

It always implies leaving out the unimportant part and saying nothing but the truth.

The word *erzählen* mainly just means telling something that will likely be a story at the end.

> Erzähl mir von deinem Wochenende!
>
> Erzählst du mir eine Gute-Nacht-Geschichte?

Whether the story is true depends on the context; telling about the week-end implies truth while the bedtime story doesn’t. But likely you wouldn’t leave out all too much, even if it’s unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

"berichten" ist im sachlichen Stil die notwendigen Informationen zu einem Sachverhalt darstellen wie es etwa in einem Unfallbericht der Polizei der Fall ist.

Ķinder wollen ein Märchen erzählt haben mit allen unterhaltenden Ausschmückungen und keinen klapperdürren Bericht der Fakten.